# Cocos2dx replaceScene with CCTransitionFade

Tags: cocos2d-x

Pressing the button changes the scene I have delayed this:

```
CCDirector :: sharedDirector () -> replaceScene (CCTransitionFade :: create (5, GameScene :: scene (), ccWHITE));
```

but while it will change completely, GameScene actions already taking place as 5 seconds. How to make that action happen began after a complete download?

Comment: What you want do to actually, explain it

Comment: CCDirector::sharedDirector->replaceScene(CCTransitionCrossFade::create(.2f,yourSceneName));

Comment: Here it goes, but how to make this transition with color, like mine?

Answer (score 0):

Try! it work for me!! You have to make a ColorLayer for coloring effect in Scene transition

CCDirector* myDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();

CCScene* myScene = CCScene::create();
 CCLayerColor myColorLayer=CCLayerColor::create(ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255));

pDirector->replaceScene(CCTransitionCrossFade::create(2f,myScene->addChild(myColorLayer,10)));

Comment: may have other options?

Comment: I checked the action taking place on stage (CCLog and all collisions have already processed), but just can not see them, and then abruptly everything happens. Therefore, this option will not work (

Comment: try the code color 244,252,10,62. May it was black that's it ain't showing anything.

Comment: You do not understand. The fact that no CCTransitionCrossFade takes action on the other stage. In fact, if the scene is a timer after it has booted scene he abruptly jumps to the time that you put in CCTransitionCrossFade. Ie actually all actions committed, the timer goes collision bodies were calculated. Pomoymu there is what that method OnEnterDidFinish but I do not value. Sorry for my English)

Comment: Send me your code at kandoi.sumit@gmail.com.  Why you need scene transition with a coloring effect? infact,there are lot of cool transition effects in cocos2dx.